# the presentation of the 3 D objects is invisible using mac

Tags: macos, 3d, anylogic, invisible

I am doing the job shop example on the Anylogic in 3 days.
I added a custom type agent (ForkliftTruck) for a new resource unit (forklifts).
However, the 3D object is invisible (its properties show it's visible tho!). I also tried to remove it and add a new forklift truck presentation from the 3D object palette, but it is still invisible. The truck does not show in the simulation either. Does anyone know how to fix the problem? Thx!
I am using mac, and I am not sure if it is a bug in mac version again...

[image]

Comment: probably a mac bug, yes. Do you see the 3d subfolder in your model folder?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue…

Comment: If it is a population of agents in the main. Is the representation of this population in the middle of the view of the main, this was the mistake I made before.

Comment: AnyLogic confiremed this as a bug.. looking into it... the object will display in a 3D window... but not in 2D or in the design view....